# Reading a controll character in a loop in Python

Tags: python

I have a code snippet below and because of habit from other programming languages I wanted to use a `do-while` loop instead. But Python offers only the construct which I show as a second code snippet instead of a `do-while*`loop.
What is the best pythonic way to code this?

```
ch = getch()
while ch != "q":
  do_something()
  ch = getch()


while True:
  ch = getch()
  do_something()
  if ch == "q":
    break
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to do this with [Python List Comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) (chapter 5.1.4) as follows:

(Notice that I used `sys.stdin.read(1)` instead of `getch()`)

```
>>> import sys
>>> while [x for x in sys.stdin.read(1) if x != 'q']:
...   print x  # substitute this with your do_something()
... 


a
a


b
b


c
c


q
>>>
```

You could also use, which is a bit uglier to me:

```
>>> while [] != [x for x in sys.stdin.read(1) if x != 'q']:
```

Comment: Both of these are neat hacks, but the fact that 'x' is visible outside the list comprehension is arguably a wart in Python. I think that both alternatives in the original question express the intent better.

Comment: @akaihola, ya when I was playing around with it, I was surprised I could get at 'x'. I'll try to think of another alternative that returns and uses a list instead, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Another way would be using a generator expression. This has the effect of separating the 'control logic' and the 'action logic' (and are extremely useful!).

```
def getchar_until_quit():
    while True:
        ch = getch()
        if ch != "q": 
            yield ch
        else:
            raise StopIteration

for ch in getchar_until_quit():
    do_something()
do_something() # to process the 'q' at the end
```

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to raise a StopIteration explicitly. Maybe just break on "q", else yield.